# What is the named struct in gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Look at the codes: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html

```
publishing {
  publications {
    myPublicationName(MavenPublication) {
      // Configure the publication here
    }
  }
}
```

There are two script blocks: `publishing`, `publications`. Gradle is based on `groovy` so I guess block script is a type of method like:

```
def publishing(Closure closure)
```

But, what is the `myPublicationName(MavenPublication)`?  `myPublicationName` is a random name (there is no possible a method named `myPublicationName`, its dynamic not prepared), and MavenPublication is a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with strict Groovy logic (whether this is true for Gradle might be
a different question), this is handling a [missing
method](https://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_methodmissing).

`x(y) { ... }` is syntactic sugar for `x(y, { ... })` (Groovy allows to
exclude a closure from the regular arguments, if it's last).

It works roughly like this:

```
class Publications {
    def publications = [:]
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        publications[name] = args 
    }
    def call(c) {
        c.delegate = this
        c.call()
    }
}


def publications = new Publications()
publications {
    test(42)
}

assert [test: [42]] == publications.publications
```

If you want to dig into this specifically for Gradle, you can start from
here:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/9b23f11cf260d5d945b34625849a369937d46f94/subprojects/publish/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publish/PublishingExtension.java#L81-L108

Comment: Does `whether this is true for Gradle might be a different question` means Gradle use a custom `non-strict` and pre-compiled groovy?

Comment: If you follow the link to the source above, you will see, that this is way more structured/typed than my example code (at least in current versions, that e.g. also allow configuration via kotlin). I read your question as "Gradle does this thing. They use groovy. So how can I do that with groovy?" - if you are only interested in the Gradle specifics, then my answer is to generic.